# Complexity of Determining Linear Separability

Tags: complexity-classes

Be $X := \{x_1,...,x_N\}$ and $Y := \{y_1,...,y_N\}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

What is/are the most efficient existing algorithm/s for determining whether X and Y are linearly separable and what is its/their computational complexity (O notation and P/LP/NP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you merely want separation, then this is solved using linear programming. If you want to maximize the separation, then you're in the land of linear classification problems and max-margin classification in general.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=complexity+of+linear+programming

Comment: okay, I guess Linear Programs have always the same complexity - now that you mention it, a bell rings ;)